# Command not found when executed as sudo, but works after "sudo su"

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, sudo

If i try to run this command bash respond with not found error:

```
$ npm -v
-bash: npm: command not found
```

with sudo also:

```
$ sudo npm -v
sudo: npm: command not found
```

but works when I run first a "sudo su":

```
$ sudo su
# npm -v
6.10.3
```

Why this happens? how can I fix it to works with sudo command?

Some info:

```
type npm
npm is /root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.10.0/bin/npm
which npm
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.10.0/bin/npm
```

Comment: Please run `sudo su` and then `type npm` and `which npm` and add the output to the question.

Comment: How did you install `npm` ? Seems you installed it manually in your root directory. That is not available from your normal user, and not available in your PATH.

Comment: This looks like expected behavior when you (unwisely) install an application into /root instead of one of the usual locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login as `root`:

```
sudo su -
```

Uninstall `npm` via `nvm`:

```
nvm deactivate node && nvm uninstall node
```

Install `npm` via `apt-get`:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install npm
```

Obviously you had `npm` installed via `nvm`. `nvm` is a user-based package manager. Therefor all installed packages will not be available for other users. The solution is to use a package manager which installs packages globally on a system-basis.